# Global table enable and Dynamo DB backup and restore

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

1: How long will it take to taken the on-demand backup. Post taking the backup when we try to restore can't we restore the data in the same table ?

2: Dynamo DB is created and Global table option is not enabled. So to enable that through terraform the table needs to be empty. How can we enable this option when the table is having data?

Answer (score 0):

1. To create an on-demand backup in DynamoDB is instant. To do an on-demand backup in AWS Backup it can take up to 1 hour as it becomes a scheduled job. Unfortunately you always need to restore to a new table.
2. The table only needed to be empty for 2017 version of global tables. 2019 version which is the latest you can add a replica whenever you like. Be sure you're using the latest global table construct.